# SYN flag and sequence number - WebSocket RFC assumes it is increasing

Tags: c, networking, websocket, tcp, rfc6455

WebSocket RFC does recommend that the server terminates TCP sessions and goes into TIME_WAIT because the argument is that if the client reconnects, the TIME_WAIT socket would be *reused* because the SYN packet would have a higher sequence number. But sequence numbers in SYN are randomized! That just does not make sense. Is that recommendation really bad as seems like general consensus is that the client should be terminating the session in a normal TCP use case?

A link to WebSocket RFC about closing the session:
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-7.1.1

Comment: "a TIME_WAIT connection is immediately reopened upon
   a new SYN with a higher seq number)": this is completely incorrect. There is in fact *no such thing* as a 'TIME_WAIT *connection*'. TIME_WAIT is a *port state,* and *ports* in this state can be reused under various conditions. It is better to let the TIME_WAIT states accumulate at the client, not the server, which is done by having the server issue the first close.

Comment: When the client reconnects, it will normally use a different port number, so the relationship between the sequence numbers is irrelevant. Randomizing sequence numbers is intended for situations when the client reboots, because it no longer has memory of previous port numbers and might reuse the same port.

Comment: I submitted an RFC erratum on this.

Comment: @user207421 under which conditions, should ports be re-used in the TIME_WAIT state? would you mind posting a link to Erratum?

Comment: [Link to Erratum](https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata/eid7608). A listening port in TIME_WAIT will get reused anyway, or at least another connection can be accepted on it immediately, unless from the same client IP:port, which shouldn't happen. The ports in TIME_WAIT state just take up memory and waste lines in a `netstat` display.

Comment: @user207421 Right, that is actually exactly my point that if the client connects again with the same IP:port it would be an issue, which can happen if the client fully reboots and spams thousands of connections within a few seconds so that TIME_WAIT does not expire. Hence this server-side disconnect may be problematic because of TIME_WAIT.